# Como setar valores para config's de meu handler nos testes?

Tags: ruby, lita

Meu handler possui 4 variáveis de configuração:

```
  config :base_url
  config :details_path
  config :create_path
  config :token
```

Eu seto eles e meu arquivo lita_config, mas para testar meu handler, eu preciso setar valores para eles em meus specs também, como eu posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No rspec para o set das configurações definidas para um Handler do Lita pode ser feita utilizando `registry`. Por exemplo, no meu caso, meu handler chama `dpeauth`, para setar essas 3 variáveis de configuração podemos fazer assim:

```
registry.config.handlers.dpeauth.base_url = 'valor'
registry.config.handlers.dpeauth.details_path = 'valor'
registry.config.handlers.dpeauth.create_path = 'valor'
registry.config.handlers.dpeauth.token = 'valor'
```

Answer (score 0):

Arquivos de configurações são circunstanciais. Se em todos os seus testes você for utilizá-los, pode-se criar um aquivo `confi.rb`, ou mesmo um `fixture` para ele e fazer um `require` no seus specs. Caso, for em um teste ou outro, use um `let(:config)` ou um `before :each`.

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-2/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/file-fixture

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-4/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let